# Xamarin Reset Animation or Replace View Location After translationX Animation Ends

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to change an image view's (imgEl) X position step by step.

```
for (int i =0; i<4; i++)
{
  var animation = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(imgEl, "translationX", 50);
  animation.SetDuration(250);
  animation.Start();
}
```

Animation works one time. How do I reset image view's X position or reset animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do like this :

```
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
List<Animator> animators = new List<Animator>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

     var animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(imgEl, "translationX", i*50, (i+1)*50);
     animator.SetDuration(250);// you could custom time
     if (i > 0)
        {
        animator.StartDelay = 1000; // you could custom time
        }
        animators.Add(animator);
    }

animatorSet.SetInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animatorSet.PlaySequentially(animators);
animatorSet.Start();
```

Comment: Do you know hot to add action (event) after every step finishes and before every step starts? @LeoZhu

Comment: you could add `animator.AddListener`